# T-SQL How to select min, max and first row from table from duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

> ```
>      DateTime        --  Unit  --  Client  --- Qty
> 03/02/2013 08:00:01  --   3     --   1      ---   1
> 03/02/2013 08:00:02  --   3     --   2      ---   1
> 03/02/2013 08:00:03  --   3     --   3      ---   2
> 03/02/2013 08:00:04  --   3     --   3      ---   2
> 03/02/2013 08:00:05  --   3     --   3      ---   5
> 03/02/2013 08:00:06  --   3     --   3      ---   4
> 03/02/2013 08:00:07  --   3     --   4      ---   6
> 03/02/2013 08:00:08  --   3     --   4      ---   67
> 03/02/2013 08:00:09  --   3     --   4      ---   76
> 03/02/2013 08:00:10  --   3     --   4      ---   76
> ```

And I want :

> ```
>      DateTime        --  Unit  --  Client  --- Qty
> 03/02/2013 08:00:01  --   3     --   1      ---   1
> 03/02/2013 08:00:02  --   3     --   2      ---   1
> 03/02/2013 08:00:03  --   3     --   3      ---   2
> 03/02/2013 08:00:05  --   3     --   3      ---   5
> 03/02/2013 08:00:07  --   3     --   4      ---   6
> 03/02/2013 08:00:09  --   3     --   4      ---   76
> ```

The criteria to filter is get the min and max "Qty" from table and get only the first value when exists duplicate "Qty" values in the same "Unit" and "client" column.

I do the follow T-SQL, but the retrieval is the last "Qty" value when the "Unit" and "client" column are the same, I need the first.

```
    --1
CREATE TABLE Transact
    (DateTime   DateTime,
     Unit       INT NULL,
     Client     INT NULL,
     Qty        INT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO Transact (Datetime,Unit,Client,Qty)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:01',3,1,1)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:02',3,2,1)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:03',3,3,2)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:04',3,3,2)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:05',3,3,5)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:06',3,3,4)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:07',3,4,6)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:08',3,4,67)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:09',3,4,76)
    Values ( '03/02/2013 08:00:10',3,4,76)


DECLARE @Total TABLE
    (DateTime   DateTime,
     Unit       INT NULL,
     Client     INT NULL,
     Qty        INT NULL
    )
DECLARE @Uniques TABLE
    (DateTime   DateTime,
     Unit       INT NULL,
     Client     INT NULL,
     Qty        INT NULL
    )
DECLARE @Mini TABLE
    (DateTime   DateTime,
     Unit       INT NULL,
     Client     INT NULL,
     Qty        INT NULL
    )
DECLARE @Maxi TABLE
    (DateTime   DateTime,
     Unit       INT NULL,
     Client     INT NULL,
     Qty        INT NULL
    )
--2

INSERT INTO @Total SELECT * FROM Transact

INSERT INTO @Mini SELECT  MIN(Datetime) Datetime,Unit,Client,MIN(Qty) FROM @Total GROUP BY Unit,Client 
INSERT INTO @Maxi SELECT  MAX(Datetime) Datetime,Unit,Client,MAX(Qty) FROM @Total GROUP BY Unit,Client

--3

INSERT INTO @Uniques SELECT * FROM @Mini UNION SELECT * FROM @Maxi

SELECT * FROM @Uniques
```

Thanks in advance.

Pablo Geronimo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH MinCTE
AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Unit, PARTITION BY Client
                      ORDER BY Qty, DateTime ) AS RN
  FROM Transact
), MaxCTE
AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Unit, Client
                      ORDER BY Qty DESC, DateTime) AS RN
  FROM Transact
)
SELECT DateTime, Unit, Client, Qty FROM MinCTE WhERE RN = 1
UNION  
SELECT DateTime, Unit, Client, Qty FROM MaxCTE WhERE RN = 1;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b810/4)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(DateTime), MIN(Qty), Unit, Client FROM Transact
GROUP BY Unit, Client
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(DateTime), MAX(Qty), Unit, Client FROM Transact
GROUP BY Unit, Client
```

Comment: This query results at max datetime value record, in many equal  <Unit & Client & Qty >.

Answer (score 0):

First select the records with min and max Qty to a single table, and then select the min DateTime for those records.

```
SELECT MIN(DateTime), [Transact].Unit, [Transact].Client, [Transact].Qty 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Unit, Client, MIN(Qty) as Qty
    FROM [Transact]
    GROUP BY Unit, Client
    UNION
    SELECT Unit, Client, MAX(Qty)
    FROM [Transact]
    GROUP BY Unit, Client
    ) as MinMax
JOIN [Transact] ON [Transact].Unit = MinMax.Unit AND [Transact].Client = MinMax.Client AND [Transact].Qty = MinMax.Qty
GROUP BY [Transact].Unit, [Transact].Client, [Transact].Qty
```

I used a subquery but isn’t hard to change it to a memory table if you prefer.